# Wait for function to finish reading excel file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12

I want to read an excel file and return the data in json format. When I call 'readExcelSheet' function on button click, it returns 'undefined' as function hasn't been finished reading the excel data. On subsequent click, data does return properly. I want to wait for this function until it read complete data.

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }

readExcelSheet() {
    let dataJson;
        this.httpClient.get(this.filePath, { responseType: 'blob' })
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                    //   reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0]);
                    const bstr: string = e.target.result;
                    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

                    /* grab first sheet */
                    const wsname1: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
                    const ws1: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname1];

                    dataJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws1);
                };
                reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
            });

        return dataJson;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `subscribe`, the code executes this line asynchronously (ie: skips over this line and go to the `return` immediately). Use `lastValueFrom` in an `async-await` function instead.

Try doing this:

```
async readExcelSheet(){
 let dataJson;
 const data = await lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.get(this.filePath, { responseType: 'blob' }))
 const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

 reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  const bstr: string = e.target.result;
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

  /* grab first sheet */
  const wsname1: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
  const ws1: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname1];

  dataJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws1);
 };
 reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
 return dataJson;
}
```

Comment: It returns '[object Promise]'. I tried to fetch vale using following code and still value is 'undefined'

**Code**
var p = this.readExcelSheet();
        p.then((value) => {
            console.log("value " + value); 
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ASYNC** & **AWAIT** in your functions

```
async readExcelSheet()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `toPromise` instead of `subscribe` and then you can return the function.
You can then try to use `Promise.resolve()` to resolve the dataJson.

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
}

readExcelSheet() {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.filePath, { responseType: 'blob' })
        .toPromise().then((data: any) => {
            const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                //   reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0]);
                const bstr: string = e.target.result;
                const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

                /* grab first sheet */
                const wsname1: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
                const ws1: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname1];

                Promise.resolve(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws1))
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
        });

}
```

Comment: It returns '[object Promise]'. I tried to fetch vale using following code and still value is 'undefined'

**Code**
var p = this.readExcelSheet();
        p.then((value) => {
            console.log("value " + value); 
        });

Comment: `p = this.readExcelSheet(); p.then((value) => { console.log("value " + value); });`
Change this to `p = this.readExcelSheet().then((value) => { console.log("value " + value); });`
you need to chain your promise